# Sudo gem update --dry-run?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to make RubyGems tell if there are any updates available? I find myself constantly running `sudo gem update` -- often several times every day.

If I could run the command with a flag like --dry-run, then I could asses if the changed gems were significant to add (and also only run it when my tests on my current project were green.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you checking so often for gem updates?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
gem outdated
```

It will display all gems that need updates (listing both your current version and the latest version).

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for :)